# Do I need fast reflexes to play the Telltale game "Game of Thrones"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Even though I enjoy computer games, I have pretty much given up on them lately because I have developed a tremor in my dominant hand. I am thoroughly obsessed with the TV series Game of Thrones, and am considering buying the game to tide me over until the next season. I've read a lot of reviews and have visited the website, but I've not seen this particular question addressed.

So, particularly in combat, does this game require fast and accurate reflexes? Imagine playing this game with your non-dominant hand. Would it be frustrating?

I'll be playing on a desktop PC, using a mouse and keyboard. I played Torment a few years ago. That would be my absolute upper limit as far as reflexes go.

I'm considering the first season of:

[image: 1]

Comment: Note: if you're not using a QWERTY keyboard, there might be additional complications. When I played The Wolf Among Us (the first TTG QTE-based game), it showed the prompts as if they were for a QWERTY keyboard, while I was using an AZERTY keyboard. This meant that the button prompts actually applied to completely different buttons than I am used to, to the point of most of them being in other locations. I'm not sure whether GoT has the same issue, but it's worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 31):

From personal experience, game of thrones' QTEs (quick time events, often requiring the press of a button or directional input within a smallish timeframe to carry out actions ingame) aren't as intense as The Walking Dead and other Telltale games. Combat in Telltale's Game Of Thrones isn't like full-on mouse controlled attacking and blocking, just simple QTEs. Although sometimes you might need fairly quick reflexes (probably about a 3 second window to pull off a QTE), if you fail it, you're put right before it, and now since you know where and what it is and it should be easier to perform. If the QTEs are a deal breaker for you, you should know within the first two hours, and if you're buying on steam you should be able to refund it if that's the case.

Comment: That's helpful information, especially about steam.

Comment: No problem, http://store.steampowered.com/steam_refunds/

"Valve will, upon request via help.steampowered.com, issue a refund for any reason, if the request is made within fourteen days of purchase, and the title has been played for less than two hours."

Comment: Great answer! It might be useful to mention that QTE = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_time_event -- I had to look that up!

Comment: Thanks. Will append! Kinda get into the mind set of "oh everyone knows this stuff" sometimes.

Comment: Wait, 3s is a quick reflex?

Comment: If you're phased out in-front of your monitor, or an unexpected QTE occurs requiring you to orient yourself to perform it, quite possibly.

Comment: @Bergi If the event is unexpected and involves something like clicking on a moving target, sure. If you aren't familiar with Telltale games then those kind of QTEs might actually sneak up on you.

Answer (score 10):

Having played through on the Xbox One version, I found that the quick time events ([QTEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QTE)) are infrequent.  Most of your interactions will be choosing what to say.  Note that you have a small window for these options before you automatically give a no response/default response during dialogue.

With the QTEs, you go through a simple sequence of anywhere from 1 to around 5 actions.  You have a small window and most of the patterns repeat if you fail (although sometimes the buttons to press can change).  If you fail you are almost always taken back to the start of the QTE.

Some of the QTEs may involve mild button mashing.  It isn't too demanding but be aware if this will cause you problems.