# Is there a way to disable or lengthen Game of Thrones' timers?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Telltale's *Game of Thrones*, you get to speak often and have a really short time to answer. I'm not a native English speaker so I play with subtitles. Meaning that I have to read the subtitles, read the options and make a choice. And because of all that, it happens rather often that I don't know what to answer before the timer is out.

So is there any way to improve that experience and letting me actually ponder the choice I want to make by either disabling or lengthening the timers?

Note that I don't have [troubles with QTEs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/284014/25745) though as it's just pressing buttons for me: only in dialogs.

I'm playing the PS4 version of the game.

Comment: Try pressing the menu button, I don't know about ps4 but on ps3 it brought up a transparent menu through which you could still read the choices.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray It's been my go-to helper right now, so I can try and understand my possible outcomes from what I hear rather than what I read (which is more imprecise), but alas the menu isn't transparent on PS4. It's a good thing to let PS3 owners to know.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but afaik there is no other way. I would suggest you to write TellTale about it, many people are having such issues and if enough people ask for it they might implement a pause.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a way to do this in any of the Telltale games, as the timer is an important part of these games. The point of the timer is to force the player to choose their instinctive choice, rather than weighing out all of the options.

For someone who is not a native English speaker, this is unfortunate.